# Ошибка NullPointerException при авторизации через twitter

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.
Реализовываю авторизацию в android приложении через twitter, большая часть кода досталась от предыдущего разработчика.

```
private final TwitterAuthClient twitterAuthClient== new TwitterAuthClient();;
private final AtomicReference<SocialLoginResult> reference= new AtomicReference<>();
private final TwitterAuthCallback twitterAuthCallback = new TwitterAuthCallback();
   @Override
    public void startLogin(@NonNull Object startActivityForResultObject) {
        if (startActivityForResultObject instanceof Fragment || startActivityForResultObject instanceof Activity) {
            reference.set(null);
            if (startActivityForResultObject instanceof Fragment) {
                Fragment fragment = (Fragment) startActivityForResultObject;
                twitterAuthClient.authorize(new Activity() {
                    @Override
                    public void startActivityForResult(@RequiresPermission Intent intent, int requestCode) {
                        fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
                    }


                    @Override
                    public PackageManager getPackageManager() {
                        return fragment.getContext().getPackageManager();
                    }
                }, twitterAuthCallback);
            } else {

                twitterAuthClient.authorize((Activity) startActivityForResultObject, twitterAuthCallback);
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't startActivityForResult on this object " + startActivityForResultObject);
        }
    }
```

При выполнении `startLogin` в строке `return fragment.getContext().getPackageManager();` вываливается ошибка:

> "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null
>   object reference"

Прошу знающих людей подсказать как устранить данную ошибку и/или скинуть ссылку на статью об авторизации в android приложении через twitter.

Comment: `fragment.getContext()` возвращает `null`, так как фрагмент `fragment` не ассоциирован ни с каким контекстом, проще говоря, данный фрагмент не имеет активити-хоста, то есть он просто где-то в воздухе витает.

Comment: хм...А как фрагмент ассоциировать с активити?

Comment: [Adding a fragment to an activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: Проверил , fragment.getContext возвращает не null.

Comment: Но при этом Вы получаете тот же самый экзепшн?

Comment: угу, мб это как то связано с api twitter?

Comment: Поставьте брейкпоинт на строку `return fragment.getContext().getPackageManager();` и посмотрите какой именно объект является `null`.